# Pdf download from url, save it in a file, zip then download the zip

Tags: javascript, angular, blob, jszip

Have been using jszip to create and download the zip file. I am able to download the pdf file separately. but I want to download these pdf into the zip folder and then download the zip file.

code snippet to download the pdf:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       window.location.href = "pdf_url"
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "pdf_url");
xhttp.send();
```

adding the zip api to it:

```
    var zip = new JSZip();
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           window.location.href = "pdf_url"
           zip.file("file_name", pdf_url_content);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "pdf_url");
    xhttp.send();
```

creating zip :

```
  zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
    .then(function callback(blob) {
      saveAs(blob, "example.zip");
    }
```

the pdf_url_content should have the content of the url. how to read that content? I tried using jszip-utils. Not able to proceed. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it would be useless to zip the pdf, because the user will download it un-zipped with the xmlhttprequest then zipped, so he will have to download the file twice for nothing.

I answered anyway for your information

You should set the proper content-type to your `xmlhttprequest`, and the `responseType` to `blob`. Then you can access the content of the pdf using the property `response` inside the `onreadstatechange` callback

```
var zip = new JSZip();
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "pdf_url");
xhttp.responseType = "blob";
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/pdf");
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       zip.file("file_name", xhttp.response);
       zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
          .then(function(blob) {
               saveAs(blob, "example.zip");
          });
    }
};

xhttp.send();
```

Note that you need `FileSaver.js` for the downloading part (`saveAs` function).